# use some properties from based class in every child class

Tags: c#, oop

is there any way from which I can give some properties to child class?

I have a scenario in which all child class contains properties from base but not all properties.

Suppose I have properties for all classes

```
public string AAAAA    { get; set; }
public string ABbbb    { get; set; }
public string ACCCCC   { get; set; }
public string ADDDDDD  { get; set; }
public string AEEEEE   { get; set; }
public string BBBBBB   { get; set; }
public string BBBAAA   { get; set; }
public string CCCCAAA  { get; set; }
public string DDDAAAA  { get; set; }
```

where in class A I only wants

> AAAAA
>
> BBBAAA

properties, in class B I want every properties, in class C only want

> ACCCCC
>
> BBBAAA

and so on.. is there any way through which I do this?

Comment: No. To solve your problem you should "prefer composition over inheritance".

Comment: It seems you don't have a base class, you have a kitchen sink.

Comment: No, it voilates OOPs concept. Rather create other classes with property groups you want and use them in your classes.

Answer (score 3):

I think that what you want to reach is something like this :

```
public interface ITypeAny
{
    string MyCommonProperty { get; set; }
}

public interface ITypeA : ITypeAny
{
    string AAA { get; set; }
}

public interface ITypeB : ITypeAny
{
    string BBB { get; set; }
}

public abstract class TypeAny : ITypeAny
{
    public string MyCommonProperty { get; set; }
}

public class TypeA : TypeAny, ITypeA
{
    public string AAA { get; set; }
}

public class TypeB : TypeAny, ITypeB
{
    public string BBB { get; set; }
}
```

This way you can have common properties for all your child classes (you see them as `ITypeAny`) and in the same time have specific properties for some of your child classes (in this case you must see them as `ITypeA` or `ITypeB`).

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are great as they try to help you along, disregarding the lack of concrete examples. 
This answer tries to be straight up. Your question:

> is there any way from which I can give some properties to child class?
>
> I have a scenario in which all child class contains properties from base but not all properties.

**No**, there is no way to make a child class inherit only certain properties from a base class.

You should rethink your design, and possibly get back with a more specific, concrete question. (Also, perhaps you have an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?)

Answer (score -2):

You can use modifiers like private, public etc. to let members be accessed from child classes. Once the base class has members with public, internal or protected modifiers, you cannot hide them from sibling classes. All siblings will have the ability to access those members. In your case, you have to put the common members to base class and put all others into their own class.

Since you cannot use multiple inheritance in C#, you can either use composition or put entity specific members to their own classes as explained above.